# Shopify Webhooks are not working in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, shopify, shopify-app

I am working on shopify app in laravel. I am facing issue to get response of shopify web-hooks which I have added in shopify store at the time of app installation. I have create a route in web.php:

```
Route::any('/uninstall','uninstallController@index');
```

But I am unable to get response in Controller.

On other hand, when I have created a file in public folder and added it as target file, then I have got a response of my web-hook.

Why am I not getting response of my web-hook in my controller?
I am also trying to get response in route by creating function but didn't get anything.

Comment: Do you have a `uninstallController`? Is it not called `UninstallController`? What does the `index()` method look like in your `UninstallController`? How are you testing the page?

Comment: @ThomasEdwards Yes, I have already created uninstallController in laravel and index() is method in my function where I am trying to write a log file using hook response but I didn't get any thing yet.

Comment: Can you show us that code?

Answer (score 3):

There Can be two main reason for that.

1) Webhook could not created successfully. to check this Please make API call with 
   GET Request

```
GET /admin/api/2019-10/webhooks.json
```

If you did not get your desired webhook in the response please create it

2) In Laravel spacific development,you need to bypass VerifyCsrfToken middle-ware for your webhook route
   as Laravel will not allow & blocks cross site requests default.to do so please follow below steps.

Go to **app/http/middleware/VerifyCsrfToken** & add your route in the **$except** array.

As Example :

```
protected $except = [
  '/app/uninstalled-webhook-shopify/*',
  '/products/create-webhook-shopify/*',
];
```